# how to get values monthly from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `lead` and there is a field called `added_on (datatype timestamp)`, I want to to fetch only the leads which are interested in a particular product and the reports should come monthly.

`interested_in` is a field in the lead table where the interested product's id will be stored as a comma separated values.

and `$prod_id` is stored with a product id which has to be checked.

the below query works fine just to fetch out the leads which are interested in a particular product. but i want the results to come month by month.

```
select*from lead where find_in_set('$prod_id',interested_in)
```

Please guide me what i have to do to achieve that

Comment: does the lead table contains date field ?

Comment: Please specify the datatype of `added_on`

Comment: Sorry...the data type of added_on is a timestamp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY

`WHERE MONTH(added_on) = $giveMonthNumber`

OR

`WHERE MONTHNAME(added_on) = $givenMonthName;`

Reference :
[MySQL date time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: but that will just group up the results isnt it ?..the problem is i want to display the results only belong to a particular month.

Comment: then use `WHERE`  instead of `GROUP BY`

Comment: is it posible to enter the month which the results should be fetched?

Comment: perfect :) it works..thanks alot diEcho! I appreciate your help and patience

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
select * from lead where find_in_set('$prod_id',interested_in) group by added_on
```